# Pushing to GitHub without a key

Tags: github, c9.io

I am using GitHub and C9 on a work computer and but GitHub will stop reading my SSH key after a few hours.  IDK if it is because I am using my work computer (job is not currently programming), but is there a way I can push my code without an SSH key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that your remote URL is indeed an ssh one:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/cloned/repo
git remote -v
```

If it is (`git@github.com:user/repo`), check what `ssh -Tv git@github.com` returns.

If SSH does not work (because SSH port might be blocked at work), switch to an HTTPS URL:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo
```

From there, make sure git config credential.helper does reference an helper (like "manager" on Windows), and you will be prompted for your GitHub account username/password at the first push. After that, your credentials will be cached.